# R and Excel: Space which is not a common space gives in R

Tags: r, excel, space

I have an Excel sheet with columns where some entries contains at the end of the string a space. For example: "SS" and "SS ", the last with space. This is only visible if I click in the cell. When I try to replace the space using space bar with "" and ctrl+h it does not find the space. Obviously, it is not a common space. I tried to insert a common space somewhere else (with space bar) and I can find this (space-bar)-space. So, I assume that it is a special space. If I copy the space in that cell and use it with ctrl+h then I can replace it with "".

When I import the Excel sheet into R (using ess-emacs) before replacing I get the following entries:

[image]

The underscore is not a common underscore and can't be replaced with "" by using `sub`. Now, I'm wonder what this space is and how can I cope with this in R (that is removing this space/underscore).

Comment: Especially if the data source is html or web document, those *spaces* are frequently the `NBSP` code `160`.  You can find/replace them in Excel by entering the code into the find box by holding down the `alt` while typing `0160` on the **numeric keypad**

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks. This is the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't guarantee that this will work (since Unicode etc. handling can vary from platform to platform), but `?trimws` suggests that using `whitespace = "[\\h\\v]"` will work:

```
> z <- data.frame(1:2,2:3)
> names(z) <- c("a  ","b\u00a0")  ## column name with Unicode space
> z
  a   b 
1   1  2
2   2  3
> names(z)
[1] "a  " "b " 
> trimws(names(z))  ## default doesn't remove space after 'b'
[1] "a"  "b "
> trimws(names(z), whitespace="[\\h\\v]")
[1] "a" "b"
```